# Xcode Syntax Coloring Broken in .mm Files

Tags: xcode, syntax-highlighting, objective-c++

I've been trying to debug this issue for weeks now and I have made zero progress. In one of my projects, my .mm files no longer have the proper syntax coloring except for things like @property, @synthesize and primitive types like BOOL, int, double, etc. The .cpp files are fine. I've tried just about every 'fix' I could find on the web. I've:

1. Deleted the 'Derived Data' for the project under Organizer.
2. Right-clicked on the project's .xcodeproject file in Finder, selected 'Show Package Contents' and deleted all but the .pbxproj file.
3. Product > Clean
4. Messed around with the Editor > Syntax Coloring options.
5. Ensured that all of my Header Search Paths were using the '$(SRCROOT)/' prefix.
6. Ensured that all of the header files to be imported from these paths were imported by:

   ```
   #import <header.h>
   ```

instead of:

```
    #import "header.h"
```

I feel like I'm out of options. Does anyone else have a fix that is different from the things I've already tried hundreds of times? Not having the proper syntax coloring is driving me insane.

Thanks.

EDIT: Forgot to mention, I also looked at the log in Console.app and saw this:

12/5/11 3:08:08 PM  Xcode[7623] [?T] IDEIndexingClangInvocation: Failed to save PCH file: /Users/jinser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ABBYY_MenuApp-ezwvcbulelfqwkftuwttlogvxsym/Index/PrecompiledHeaders/OpenCV_iPhone_Prefix-bqbegypvoktytjhgrfdzxrzeamix_ast/OpenCV_iPhone_Prefix.pch.pth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you ever modify your .pch file? If you have a .pch file that isn't strictly correct, this can break the indexer. For example, if you use `#import "header.h"` where you really need `#import <EmbeddedFramework/header.h>`, this will actually compile just fine in regular files (assuming your header search paths are set up to find `header.h`) but, if present in the .pch, it will break the indexer as it's not strictly correct.

Try deleting the contents of your .pch file, then delete all DerivedData and let Xcode re-index. If things highlight correctly now, you know your .pch was the problem.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I jumped out of my seat and starting singing (no joke) when I finally saw my syntax colored properly. I went to username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData to delete the appropriate Derived Data folder instead of just using the Organizer tool in Xcode. For some reason, removing #import <Foundation/Foundation.h> from my .pch in addition to the deletion of DerivedData fix it. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Using Kevin Ballard's advice, I changed my .pch file from this:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <opencv/cv.h>
#endif
```

to:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <opencv/cv.h>
#endif
```

In Finder, I also deleted the appropriate Derived Data folder by going to username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData.

Voilà - the syntax is now colored properly. My madness is finally subsiding.

EDIT (10 Days Later): I will add however that this does not always work. My code sense is again broken and performing these steps is not fixing it. Seems like each case is unique and you have to waste hours of your time trying to fix the issue whenever this happens. Hopefully Apple can make Xcode more robust to these errors in the future.